# Form Re-Submission in ASP.Net MVC Without using jQuery Ajax Method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have below code if i submit form it submitted properly but suppose i refresh/reload page then it ask for resubmitting Form i want to solve this problem without using Ajax form Submit method or ajax post method

Refere Below Code

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Loginview(LogOnModel MD,FormCollection frmCollection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            int result = GetLoginDetails(MD);
            if (result == 100)
               return RedirectToAction("HomeView", "Home");
            else if (result == -1)
                MD.ErrorMessage = "Error Occured please Try Again Later!!";
            else
                MD.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Username or Password !!";

            //  ViewData["result"] = result; // for dislaying message after saving storing output.
            //  ModelState.Clear();

        }
```

View

```
@model MIT.Models.LogOnModel
@{

    Layout = null;

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Loginview</title>

</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
        <div class="container" align="center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-signin mg-btm">
                    <h3 class="heading-desc">
                        Login</h3>
                    <div class="main">
                        <label>
                            Email ID</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email ID", @autofocus = "autofocus", @required = "required", @type = "text" })

                        </div>
                        <label>
                            Password
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password", @required = "required", @type = "password" })

                        </div>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label class="pull-right">
                                <a href="">(Forgot Password)</a></label></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success pull-left" style="min-width: 80%;">
                                    Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label class="pull-right" style="color: Red; ">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.ErrorMessage)</label></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="clearfix"></span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: after refresh, you want to re-submit the same data again ? or you just want to do a post request ?

Comment: if suppose i refresh page  then i want to reload page or call new page instance  don't want to call post method .

Comment: suppose i have controller  
public ActionResult Loginview(LogOnModel MD) //ON load 
       
 and post MEthod 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Loginview(LogOnModel MD) //ON POST

if i refresh or reload page then debugger must go to 
public ActionResult Loginview(LogOnModel MD) 

not ON [HTTPPOST] method of view

Comment: at the end of `[HttpPost]` method you can use `RedirectToAction("Loginview");` which will redirect you back to the original `HttpGet` method

Comment: if suppose user enter wrong details then i want to show that entered values back on the form, don't want to clear form.At least show username and with error message "wrong credentials"

Comment: `If(ModelState.IsValid) { .... RedirectToAction("Loginview"); ... }` return View(MD);` you can return view outside of the model state if false

Comment: i already think on this condition actually my data is valid but not correct username password then i cant redirect to login page it will clear my form.

Comment: Put your things outside of conditions that will run if condition fails. And if you want to pass back the error then pass it with `return View(YourModel);` back to the view. This won't clear the view then.

Comment: but issue will remain same for form resubmission on refresh or reload page. if i pass model to view   return View(YourModel);

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to once your controller verifies the data is good and you process it, to redirect them to a different view. That way if they do refresh, it will not reprocess your form. Add a return View(yourmodel) at the end of the IsValid if statement to return user to orginal page.

```
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
           int result = GetLoginDetails(MD);
           if (result == 100)
           {
             //I assume this is a good result?

             //!Process and store user entered data here!

             return RedirectToAction("ResultPage", "Home"); // Take them to a page dislaying message after saving storing output.
           }
           else if (result == -1)
             MD.ErrorMessage = "Error Occured please Try Again Later!!";
           else
             MD.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Username or Password !!";
         }

         return View(model);  //this takes user back to original page display error message of what they need to correct. If model is valid, code will not get here.
```